# How to provide a custom variable to menu-account.html.twig template in drupal 8

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I want to provide the logged in user name to the twig template. So i need to pass that as a variable into the template. 
Any help would be really appreciated.

I have tried using hook_theme_registry_alter approach but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

use HOOK function hook_preprocess_page
if you are writing code in your theme then write this code into your .theme file
if in module then in .module file

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  global $user;// current user object
  $variables['customUserName'] = $user->getUsername();

}
```

change themename to your theme name if in module then replace with module name
in your twig template you will print this variable like this

```
{{ customUserName }}
```

we are overriding page template so your are able to get this variable in all you page templates
if you need this variable in node template then rename function to

```
function themename_preprocess_node(){}
```

hope this meet your requirment
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Code.rider's answer is correct, but in Drupal 8 better to use \Drupal::currentUser() to get current user. Here is my code from mytheme.theme:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
  if($user)
  {
    $username = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($user->id());
    $variables['username'] = $username->getUsername();
  }
  return $variables;
}
```